# saving the first line - Linux Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a text file and am trying to extract the data in the first row (or line) of the file, where each data is saved as a list (so each point is saved on it's own line) in a new file.

example data.txt:

```
Name  Col  Samp1  Samp2  Samp3  Samp4  Samp5  Samp6
Car1  Red   49.3   43.2   54.3   52.3   12.5   76.8
Car2  Blu   56.3   12.4   85.4   67.1   24.5   32.5
and so on..
```

I would like a new list to look like this, and saved to a new file called samps.txt:

```
Samp1
Samp2
Samp3
Samp4
Samp5
Samp6
```

I am very new to shell scripting and could use all the help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the first line into a variable

```
read -r FIRSTLINE < filename
```

Split the string into words

```
WORDS=( $FIRSTLINE )
```

Loop through the words and output them to a file

```
for WORD in ${WORDS[@]}
do
  echo $WORD >> outputfilename
done
```

In your case, you want to drop the first two column values. You can slice the array by using `${WORDS[@]:2` in your for statement. Alternative, you can test the values inside the for loop before echoing them to the file.

Comment: Hi @Enrico.  Thanks for your help thus far.  I tried your suggestions, first by testing the values inside the loop, however nothing is printing.  The script appears to run, as there are no errors, but I'm not getting the desired output.  Any advice?

Comment: @ShilaP make sure you have run the first two commands to populate the WORDS array variable before running the for loop code. Otherwise the array is empty and it won't print anything

Comment: Yes I ran the first two lines first, and it doesn't seem like WORDS is populating?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19965/discussion-between-enrico-and-shila-p)

Answer (score 2):

Use `read -a` to read the line into an [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html), and then use `for` to iterate over the array elements. See `help` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
$ head -1 data.txt | grep -o 'Samp[0-9]*'

Samp1
Samp2
Samp3
Samp4
Samp5
Samp6
```

**Explanation:**

1. Display the first line of a file: `head -1 data.txt`
2. `|` take the output of the last command and use it as input to the next (called piping).
3. Print the matches of the given `regex`: `grep -o 'Samp[0-9]*'`

The `regex` `'Samp[0-9]*'` will match any string that starts `Samp` followed by any digits.

To save the output to `samps.txt` use the redirection operator `>`:

`$ head -1 data.txt | grep -o 'Samp[0-9]*' > samps.txt`

This will work for any column headings not just ones that match `'Samp[0-9]*'`:

`$ head -1 data.txt | grep -o '\w*' | tail -n +3 > samps.txt`

`grep -o '\w*'`  matches words and `tail -n +3` displays all the lines starting at the 3rd line *(i.e. not displaying the first two column headings)*.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) a valuable tool when processing text files with fields:

```
awk 'NR==1 { for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' file
```

Results:

```
Samp1
Samp2
Samp3
Samp4
Samp5
Samp6
```

Explanation:

```
NR is short for the number of rows.
NF is short for the number of fields in the row.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using bash:

```
set -- $(head -1 data.txt)       # save the words in the first line as $1,$2,...
shift 2                          # discard the first two words
printf '%s\n' "$@" > samps.txt   # print each remaining word on its own line
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer because it's the best option, using only pure `bash`. As he doesn't give a fully working example, here's one:

```
read -a samps < "myfile.txt"
printf "%s\n" "${samps[@]:2}"
```

Output:

```
Samp1
Samp2
Samp3
Samp4
Samp5
Samp6
```